# Are character constants always positive?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I'm curious if I can compile

```
int map [] = { [ /*(unsigned char)*/ 'a' ]=1 };
```

regardless of platform or if it's better to cast character constants to `unsigned char` prior to using them as indices.

Comment: `[x]=1` is a GCC'ism. Is this related to the question?

Comment: @StaceyGirl No, it is not (anymore ;), per [C11 6.7.9p6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p6) it's a designator in array initialization. The thing is about `If the array is of unknown size, any nonnegative value is valid`.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Designated initializers (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.8) have been part of C since C99.

Comment: Hm. [6.2.5p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p3) `If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative`

Comment: @KamilCuk Now *that* is the answer.

Comment: @KamilCuk Great find. Had you posted it as an answer, I would have accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A character constant is a positive values of `int`, if it is based on a member of the basic execution-time character set.

Since `a` is in that basic character set, we know that `'a'` is required to be positive.

On the other hand, for example, `'\xFF'` might not be positive. The `FF` value will be regarded as the bit pattern for a `char`<sup>†</sup>, which could be signed, giving us a -1 due to two's complement. Similar reasoning will apply if instead of a numeric escape, we use a character that corresponds to a negative value of type `char`, like characters corresponding to the 0x80-0xFF byte range on 8-bit systems.

It was like this in ANSI C89 and C90, where I'm relying on my memory; but the requirements persist through newer drafts and standards. In the n1570 draft, we have these items:

1. 6.4.4.4 Character Constants, paragraph 10: *"If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with type char whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type int."*
2. 6.2.5 Types, paragraph 3: *"If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative."*

A character constant is not a "`char` object", but the requirements in 6.4.4.4 specify that the value of a character constant is determined using the `char` representation: *"... one that results when an object with type char whose value ..."*.

---

<sub>† The numeric escape sequences for an unprefixed character constants and those prefixed with `L` have an associated "corresponding type" which is unsigned and are required to be in that type's range (6.4.4.4 9). The idea is that character values are specified as an unsigned value, which gives their bit-wise representation which is then interpreted as `char`. This intent is also conveyed in Example 2 (6.4.4.4 13)</sub>.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194201/discussion-on-answer-by-kaz-are-character-constants-always-positive).

Answer (score 4):

> I'm curious if I can compile
>
> ```
> int map [] = { [ /*(unsigned char)*/ 'a' ]=1 };
> ```
>
> regardless of platform or if it's better to cast character constants
>   to unsigned char prior to using them as indices.

Your specific code is safe.

`'a'` is an *integer character constant*.  The language specifies of these that

> An integer character constant has type `int`. The value of an integer
>   character constant containing a single character that maps to a
>   single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
>   representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. [...]
>   If an integer character constant contains a
>   single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results
>   when an object with type char whose value is that of the single
>   character or escape sequence is converted to type int.

([C2011, paragraph 6.4.4.4/10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10))

It furthermore specifies that

> If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative.

([C2011, paragraph 6.2.5/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p3))

and it requires of every implementation that both the basic source and basic execution character sets contain, among other characters, the lowercase Latin letters, including 'a'.  ([C2011, paragraph 5.2.1/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3))

You should take care, however: an integer character constant for a character that is *not* a member of the basic execution character set, including a multibyte character, or for a multi-character integer character constant does need not to be nonnegative.  Some of those could, in principle, be negative even on machines where default `char` is an unsigned type.

Moreover, again considering multibyte characters, the cast to `unsigned char` is not necessarily safe either, in that you could produce collisions that way.  To be sure to avoid collisions, you would need to convert to `unsigned int`, but that could produce *much* larger arrays than you expect.  If you stick to the basic character sets  then you're ok.  If you stick to single-byte characters then you're ok with a cast.  If you must accommodate multibyte characters then for portability, you should probably choose a different approach.

Comment: "Some of those could, in principle, be negative even on machines where default char is an unsigned type." only with `sizeof(int) == 1`. Also a multibyte character is not a `char` :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, what do you claim prevents the value of, say, `'ab'` from being negative?  Or that of an integer character constant formed from a multibyte character?